# how to Show MDIChild Form on Top of the MDIParent's Controls

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, mdichild, mdiparent

I have a MDI-Parent Form with many ChildForms, when I want to add a control on my Parent form, Child form appears under the control, For example I want to add a groupbox and a PictureBox on MDIParent Form, but when I call the Child Form it appears Under these controls.

`frmChildForm1.TopMost=true`  doesn't works either.

I have attached a photo for more description.

What can I do?!

[image]

Comment: This is by design.  You can only set the Dock property of the control to avoid this.  Dock it on an edge so it shrinks the MDI client area.

Comment: Yes , but I want to have an Image as Background, It doesn't show and I must use a picture box , so I have yet similiar problem

Answer (score 2):

> but I want to have an Image as Background

That's possible, you can set the BackgroundImage property of the MDI client control.  The only obstacle is that you cannot directly get a reference to that control.  You have to find it back by iterating the form's Controls collection.  Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls) {
            if (ctl is MdiClient) {
                ctl.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Lighthouse;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where *Lighthouse* was a sample image I added as a resource.  Change it to use your own.  Another common technique is to subscribe the Paint event for that control and draw whatever you want.  A gradient is a common choice.

Comment: Thank You ! that was my solution :)

Comment: It worked for me but ,My BackgrounImage is repeating from `right` and `bottom` border ,Why is that so ? I also changed its Layout to `stretch` but still the same prob `foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ctl is MdiClient)
                {
                    ctl.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.bg;
                    ctl.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
                    break;
                }
            }` like this I did

Comment: Use the BackgroundImageLayout property.

Comment: You will have to click the Ask Question button.

Comment: I have posted question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520373/setting-mdiparent-background-image-properly