# Setting MdiParent Background Image properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using below code to set background image of MdiParent form ,and it is working well ,but when I click on maximize button than BackgroundImage is repeating at rightside and bottom edge(i.e right side and bottom side Image portion is repeating) ,how do I avoid this and display Image properly ?

```
public Parent()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl is MdiClient)
        {
            ctl.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.bg;
            ctl.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

`this` points to Form.

Myself too noticed the same behavior you mentioned. It seems just a painting issue. Add the following code to fix it.

```
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [MdiClient.BackgroundImageLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mdiclient.backgroundimagelayout.aspx) is not relevant for the class `MdiClient` (as stated by the MSDN document page). You should try some work-around. One of the work-around is **paint the BackgroundImage yourself**:

```
MdiClient client = Controls.OfType<MdiClient>().First();
client.Paint += (s, e) => {
   using(Image bg = Properties.Resources.bg){
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(bg, client.ClientRectangle);
   }
};
//Set this to repaint when the size is changed
typeof(Control).GetProperty("ResizeRedraw", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
              .SetValue(client, true, null);
//set this to prevent flicker
typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
               .SetValue(client, true, null);
```

Comment: The image needs to be disposed.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, I'm not sure how it should be done to dispose the image. Could you review my updated code?

Comment: @HansPassant The image is being disposed. The "using" statement disposes of the object once it's finished running

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Frmmain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is MdiClient Then
                ctl.BackgroundImage = Me.BackgroundImage
            End If
        Next ctl
        Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub Frmmain_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.SizeChanged
    Try
        Me.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```